# Why can't we increment (++) or decrement (--) number literals

Tags: javascript, numbers, increment, literals, decrement

For example, in the following JavaScript code, why do we not get errors when using variables, but when a number literal is used, I get an error (running on node v6.9.5)?

```
let x = 2;
console.log(x++); //2

let y = 2;
console.log(++y); //3

console.log(2++); //ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in postfix operation
console.log(++2); //ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side expression in prefix operation
```

My understanding is that this doesn’t work because you can’t mutate the literal 2. In the previous example, you returned x or y (either before or after incrementing), so it was now equal to +1 its previous value (so x/ y now pointed to 3, rather than 2). However, you can’t increment 2 to be +1 its previous value and then have it point to the literal 3. 2 will always be 2, 2 will never point to 3.

Am I correct in my reasoning?

Comment: `console.log(x++)` is the same as `console.log(x); x=x+1`. Substitute `2` for `x` and the second statement (`2=2+1`) attempts to store `2+1` in something that is not a variable (`2`). `console.log(++x)` is the same as `x=x+1; console.log(x)`. The same for `--`.

Comment: `++` and `--` are operations on a variable. They increment or decremented and set the value. You cant change a constant.

Comment: Actually, pre-increment and pre-decrement are valid operations on number literals in some languages such as python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Literals are constants, and increment/decrement would try to change its argument respectively. But constant values cannot be changed.

It would be the same like coding something like

```
2 = 2 + 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

The argument of a increment/decrement operator must be a *lvalue* -- essentially, it has to be an expression that you could assign a value to. This can be either a variable, or certain types of simple structured expressions (like `array[0]++` or `object.foo++`).

Constants aren't lvalues. You can't assign a value to them (`3 = abc`), nor can you mutate their values with the increment or decrement operators.